# Enity Framework for existing enterprise database

Tags: entity-framework

I am working on creating a service layer for a large sql server database (2008 R2) that is currently the backend for a winforms POS application with strongly typed datasets.

I think WCF is the way to go, and at first glance it seemed EF 4 was a good choice but now I'm having my doubts.  Here is what I have found:

1. The stored procedure mapping isn't that great.  I have hundreds of stored procs that I want to reuse.  Most of them wouldn't return an 'entity' so the stored procs would have to be mapped to a complex type.  Many of the procs use dynamic sql or temp tables so EF can't figure out what complex type to crete.    Many of the procs return multiple result sets.  I've read that EF extensions have a way to map stored procs with multiple result sets, but only for entities, so that doesn't help me.
2. Large models are a problem.  There doesn't seem to be a good way to handle large entity models.  The workaround of creating smaller models isn't that desirable and splitting the model loses design support, am I missing something?
3. EF mappings only go so far.  The stored procs that I want to reuse return projections or information from many tables into a result set.  There doesn't seem to be a way to map these results into entities, am I wrong?  I've read about combining results from 2 table into 1 entity, but that only works if the tables have the same primary key.

Are people using EF in large scale existing databases?  If not what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I've used EF on large scale databases, but as you say, the support for SPs as you have got is not great. That's not specifically a failing of EF per-se - ORMs in general work on the same principle and have the same "limitation".

If you have lots of SPs and are mapping them to datasets, you'll have to do lots of work even without SPs in terms of no longer referencing datasets and referencing your domain model types through your system, so you'd need to have some way to map your SPs to your domain model and back anyway.